# Is there a way to specify a default eslint configuration file when using ALE plugin of Vim?

Tags: javascript, vim, eslint

I'm using [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) for linting my programming code, and I have following configuration part to specify lint tool for JavaScript.

```
let g:ale_linters = {
\   'javascript': ['eslint'],
\}

let g:ale_fixers = {
\   'javascript': ['eslint'],
\}
```

It works pretty well if eslint could find there is a `.eslintrc` or `.eslintrc.json` under current project directory. However I wonder what if I just want to use Vim to edit an arbitrary JavaScript file, it will pop up a lint error message which says `aslant configuration error` due to lack of the eslint configuration file.

So I wonder if there is a way to specify a default lint configuration file if there is no eslint configuration file could be found under current project folder.

Answer (score 1):

> If you have a configuration file in your home directory (generally
>   ~/), ESLint uses it only if ESLint cannot find any other configuration
>   file.

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring